# How can I learn the current location of a Facebook/friends list user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can I learn the current location (where the user signed in to their account) of a Facebook/friends list user?

Comment: A bit invasive, don't you think, Srikanth?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but feature like this, to get you the information about the User's current login location information is not possible as it is not exposed to the present APIs.

You might instead know the location he has been to last at (or get an idea of about the same) using either [checkins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/) (now depreciated) or location attached to Posts, Photos etc where the [User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) is tagged, quoting from the User documentation about the location connection,

> Posts, statuses, and photos in which the user has been tagged at a location, or where the user has authored content (i.e. this excludes objects with no location information, and objects in which the user is not tagged).